# Is it possible to pull constant out of this summation

Tags: summation, constants

I'm trying to prove the following:

$$ F(\alpha x) = \sum_{m=1}^M \bigl( \sum_{i=1}^N (\alpha x_i)^{\omega_m}\bigl)^{1/{\omega_m}} = \alpha F(x) $$

But I can't quite understand how to pull $\alpha$ out. I got to the following step. But if ${\omega_m}$ depends on $m$ from the outermost summation, is it possible to pull $\alpha$ out again?

$$ \sum_{m=1}^M (\alpha)^{\omega_m} \bigl(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^{\omega_m}\bigl)^{1/{\omega_m}}  $$

Comment: Do you mean $1/\omega_m$ instead of $1/\omega$?

Comment: What values do $m$ and $i$ start at? Also: what is $\omega_m$?

Comment: In the last equation I think you should get $\alpha^{\omega_m/\omega}$ in the first sum. But I still think this linearity wouldn't be true in general (unless there is a particular relationship between $\omega_m$ and $\omega$).

Comment: I've updated the equation to fix my mistake with $1/{\omega_m}$

Comment: In this case wouldn't I actually have $\alpha$ on its own pulled out from the second summation after multiplying the exponents $\omega_m * 1/{\omega_m}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pull the $\alpha$ from the inner summation, I think you've misplaced your parenthesis:

$$ \sum_{m=1}^M \bigl(\alpha^{\omega_m} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^{\omega_m}\bigl)^{1/\omega_m}  $$